# Error Parsing XML: not well formed (invalid token)

Tags: xml, android-layout, layout

I'm receiving the following message when compiling my android project:

> Error Parsing XML: Not well-formed (Invalid token)

This is the XML layout file where the error is supposed to be:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pH_View"
                android:text="pH= "
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10sp"

                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pH_Data"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ph_Graph"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/pH_View"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/pH_View"

                />
            <Button
                android:text="Graph"
                android:id="@+id/ph_Graph"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/pH_View"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/EC_View"
                android:text="EC (uS/cm2)= "
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/pH_View"

                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/EC_Data"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/EC_Graph"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/EC_View"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <Button
                android:text="Graph"
                android:id="@+id/EC_Graph"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/EC_View"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/DO_View"
                android:text="Dissolved Oxygen= "
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/EC_View"

                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/DO_Data"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/EC_Graph"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/DO_View"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <Button
                android:text="Graph"
                android:id="@+id/DO_Graph"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/DO_View"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/resTemp_View"
                android:text="Reservoir Temp (C)= "
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/DO_View"

                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/resTemp_Data"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="None"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/EC_Graph"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/resTemp_View"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <Button
                android:text="Graph"
                android:id="@+id/resTemp_Graph"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/resTemp_View"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
            <TextView
               android:id="@+id/groveTemp_View"
               android:text="Grove Temp (C)= "
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
               android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
               android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
               android:textSize="20sp"
               android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
               android:layout_below="@id/resTemp_View"
               />

          <TextView
               android:id="@+id/groveTemp_Data"
               android:textSize="18sp"
               android:text="None"
               android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/EC_Graph"
               android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/groveTemp_View"
               android:layout_margin="5dp"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               />

            <Button
                android:text="Graph"
                android:id="@+id/groveTemp_Graph"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/groveTemp_View"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="40dp">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/requestConnection"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Request Connection"
                android:onClick="requestConnection"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/requestReading"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Request Reading"
                android:onClick="requestReading"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                />

       </>

   </LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone help me find where the problem is? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`</>` is not a valid token in an XML file.

The closing tag of the `RelativeLayout` should be `</RelativeLayout>`

Comment: @jamesokbo No problem, sometimes these things happen.  Please accept this answer if it solved your problem!  Good luck!